# Jupyter/Python code to directly retrieve sequence data from Uniprot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bioinformatics

I am trying to work on Uniprot directly from my jupyter notebook. My search keywords are
TERM "tumor+necrosis+factor+receptor" and ORGANISM "Homo speiens"  Here's how far I have succeeded
Code

```
import requests
BASE = 'http://www.uniprot.org'
KB_ENDPOINT = '/uniprot/'
TOOL_ENDPOINT = '/uploadlists/'
fullURL = ('http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?'
'query=name%3A%22tumor+necrosis+factor+receptor%22+AND+taxonomy%3Ahuman+AND+reviewed%3Ayes&'
'format=list')
result = requests.get(fullURL)
if result.ok:
    print(result.text)
else:
    print('Something went wrong ', result.status_code)
```

This gives me only partial list of proteins.the actual serach on uniprot gives over 400 entries.
Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I think it isn't a problem with your code, but with the query itself. Using the "Download" button on UniProt website with [appropriate search options](https://uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=tumor%20necrosis%20factor%20receptor&fil=organism%3A%22Homo+sapiens+%28Human%29+%5B9606%5D%22+AND+reviewed%3Ayes) I got an equivalent, working query (see comment below).

Comment: The working query (as of today) is: [`query=tumor%20necrosis%20factor%20receptor&format=list&fil=organism:%22Homo%20sapiens%20(Human)%20[9606]%22%20AND%20reviewed:yes`](https://uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=tumor%20necrosis%20factor%20receptor&format=list&fil=organism:%22Homo%20sapiens%20(Human)%20[9606]%22%20AND%20reviewed:yes). Maybe you are looking at an outdated tutorial for the API?

Comment: This Works .. great .. thanks

Comment: @krassowski Also, I would appreciate if you could recommend more reading/practicing material related to it please. Thanks

Comment: Just an update since I stumbled upon this...  As of Summer 2022, there's a Python package for querying UniProt's new REST API. See [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/286919/#9537049) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73587249/8508004) for more with links therein and working code. (Code was working at the time. YMMV.)