# Web scraping table from UniProt database

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of UniProt IDs and would like to use BeautifulSoup to scrap a table containing the structure information. The url I am using is as follows: https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P03496, with accession "P03496".

A snippet of the html code is as follows.

```
<div class="main-aside">
    <div class="content entry_view_content up_entry swissprot">
        <div class="section" id="structure">
            <protvista-uniprot-structure accession="P03468">
                <div class="protvista-uniprot-structure">
                    <div class="class=" protvista-uniprot-structure__table">
                        <protvista-datatable class="feature">
                            <table>...</table>
                        </protvista-datatable>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </protvista-uniprot-structure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The information I require is contained between the `<table>...</table>` tag.

I tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P03468'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')
soup.find("protvista-datatable", {"class": "feature"})
print(soup)
```

Comment: Would it be easier to use the REST interface? https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/P03496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content is provided dynamically and is not contained in your `soup` if you take a deeper look. It do not need `BeautifulSoup`to get data, your tabel is based on, simply use their api / rest interface to get structured data as JSON:

```
import requests
url='https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprot/P03468'
## fetch the json response
data = requests.get(url).json()
## pick needed data e.g. 
data['uniProtKBCrossReferences']
```

##### Output

```
[{'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'J02146',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAA43412.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'AF389120',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAM75160.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'EF467823',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'ABO21711.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'CY009446',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'ABD77678.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'K01031',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAA43415.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'RefSeq',
  'id': 'NP_040981.1',
  'properties': [{'key': 'NucleotideSequenceId', 'value': 'NC_002018.1'}]},
 {'database': 'PDB',
  'id': '6WZY',
  'properties': [{'key': 'Method', 'value': 'X-ray'},
   {'key': 'Resolution', 'value': '1.50 A'},
   {'key': 'Chains', 'value': 'C=181-190'}]},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a Python package, [Unipressed](https://multimeric.github.io/Unipressed/), by Michael Milton ([@multimeric](https://twitter.com/multimeric)) that allows programmatic access query UniProt's new REST API.
**Example:**

```py
from unipressed import UniprotkbClient
UniprotkbClient.fetch_one("P03468")["uniProtKBCrossReferences"]
```

### Output

```
[{'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'J02146',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAA43412.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'AF389120',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAM75160.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'EF467823',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'ABO21711.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'CY009446',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'ABD77678.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'EMBL',
  'id': 'K01031',
  'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAA43415.1'},
   {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'},
   {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'Genomic_RNA'}]},
 {'database': 'RefSeq',
  'id': 'NP_040981.1',
  'properties': [{'key': 'NucleotideSequenceId', 'value': 'NC_002018.1'}]},
 {'database': 'PDB',
  'id': '6WZY',
  'properties': [{'key': 'Method', 'value': 'X-ray'},
   {'key': 'Resolution', 'value': '1.50 A'},
   {'key': 'Chains', 'value': 'C=181-190'}]}, ... ]
```

See more examples of using Unipressed to access Uniprot's new REST API [here in my reply to Biostar's post 'Accessing UNIPROT using REST API'](https://www.biostars.org/p/286919/#9537049). See using Unipressed for ID mapping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586628/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586386/8508004) and at [the bottom here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9560315/#9560336) I include converting the 'from - to' results list into a Pandas dataframe.